# Random Images two locations same set

Tags: javascript

So basically what I am looking for is how to have a random image javascript code but the images are in two different divs but I would like the random images to come from the same array.

I plan to take a JS class this summer so I don't have to ask anymore because I feel like this should be simple...

Currently I am just using the code from javascript kit in two different locations:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1]="image1.gif"
    myimages[2]="image2.gif"
    myimages[3]="image3.gif"
    myimages[4]="image4.gif"
    myimages[5]="image5.gif"
    myimages[6]="image6.gif"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
    if (ry==0)ry=1
    document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

but what I hope to achieve is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1]="image1.gif"
    myimages2[1]="image1a.gif"
    myimages[2]="image2.gif"
    myimages2[2]="image2a.gif"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
    if (ry==0) ry=1
    document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

RENDERED CODE WITHIN DIVS

```
<div class="one"><img src="img1.gif"></div>
<div class="two"><img src="img1a.gif"></div>
```

REFRESHED

```
<div class="one"><img src="img2.gif"></div>
<div class="two"><img src="img2a.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are wanting to do, I don't see the point to store them on arrays and do complex stuff to get them.

If the URL paths are the same, there is no need to chose them from an array:

```
function refreshImages() {
    var max = 10;
    var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1); //1-10
    var src1 = "http://example.com/image" + rand + ".gif";
    var src2 = "http://example.com/image" + rand + "a.gif";

    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + src1 + "' />";
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<img src='" + src2 + "' />";
}

window.onload = function() {//need to wait until the divs are loaded
    refreshImages();
}​
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**Note:** I added `+1` to `rand` because in your example you started at `image1`, if you want the possibility to start at `image0`, just remove the `+1` and the range of possibilities will change to `0-9`

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ9ee/2/) (because the images don't exist, you need to see the source code)

Comment: I actually really like this script because it does something that none of the others seem to do which is call the specific set together aka image1a AND image1. However, how would you make the code write <img src="image" + rand + ".gif"> and then how will I be able to make str1 in one div and str2 in another?

Comment: @lemonyguac added the complete example

Comment: Sorry back again. So I'm just worried about my bandwidth as far as the site goes, what would I need to change if it is an array and the image names aren't set.

Comment: Hmm ok I think I may need help still because I tried to fix it because the image names are going to be like: http://1nau7.pichost.gif and so I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/hJJ3a/2/

Answer (score 2):

Here's one particular approach.

I start out by identifying all of the variables I plan on using:

```
var rIndex1, rIndex2, 
    oContainer1, oContainer2, 
    aImages;
```

Now I assign initial references to DOM containers, as well as populate my images array:

```
oContainer1 = document.getElementById("left");
oContainer2 = document.getElementById("right");
aImages = ['http://placekitten.com/200/200','http://placekitten.com/201/201',
           'http://placekitten.com/202/202','http://placekitten.com/203/203',
           'http://placekitten.com/204/204','http://placekitten.com/205/205'];
```

Because I'll be generating random index values a few times, I create a simple function for this logic:

```
function rIndex ( iMax ) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * iMax );
}
```

In order to see the effect over and over, I'm running the logic within an anonymous function, stored within an interval that runs every second. You, of course, could just wrap it up in a named function to be called once.

```
setInterval(function(){
```

Setting initial random values for my index variables.

```
  rIndex1 = rIndex( aImages.length );
  rIndex2 = rIndex( aImages.length );
```

We don't want both images to be the same, so as long as we have selected identical values, let's choose another index value for the second index.

```
  while ( rIndex2 == rIndex1 ) rIndex2 = rIndex( aImages.length );
```

Lastly, I overwrite the innerHTML property of the containers with new image elements.

```
  oContainer1.innerHTML = '<img src="%s" />'.replace( /%s/, aImages[ rIndex1 ] );
  oContainer2.innerHTML = '<img src="%s" />'.replace( /%s/, aImages[ rIndex2 ] );

}, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubuxoj/edit#javascript,html

This could be improved upon a bit. For instance, it's possible that while `aImages[2]` is currently being shown in `oContainer2`, it may be reapplied the next time around. You could check to make sure you only select an image other than that which is currently being displayed in your container.

Comment: the `iMax ` on `rIndex` is really not the max, and choosing randomly images from an array is only advisable when their URL vary one from the another, but for just little changes I would apply this little random change directly

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to be extensible (e.g., if you don't know how many images you will have), I would normally recommend appending to the DOM and creating the `<div/>` randomly as well, and also looping to create the divs so you don't need to create them manually. However, if this is not the case, by using the pattern you have used, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
var random = Math.random();
function random_imglink(arr){
    var ry = Math.floor(random*arr.length);
    document.write(
        '<img src="'+arr[ry]+'" border=0>'
    );
}  
var myimages = [
       "image1.gif", "image2.gif"
      ],
        myimagesA = [
       "image1a.gif", "image2a.gif"
      ];
</script>
<div class="one"><script>random_imglink(myimages);</script></div>
<div class="two"><script>random_imglink(myimagesA);</script></div>
```

We first make a random number which we reuse throughout the life of the script on this page load. Then we define the writing function and then make our 2 arrays available so they can be referenced by the function calls within the divs. It's hard to know exactly what you want without more detail, but hopefully this will give some ideas.

Comment: your random doesn't change between calls

Comment: It does on page loads which is what the examples in the description appear to be describing.

Comment: well, while it works because he want the image2 to be the same of image1 but with "a" (and moving the random var inside the function will ruin this)... the function can't be used to generate more than one random pair

Comment: I already explained in my note that I would personally make it more extensible; I am only incrementally following the pattern started by the self-professed beginner to make it clear how it can be adapted, and if he doesn't need more than one random pair, it might be all he needs.

Comment: Your code, if you want to be picky, suffers from not being extensible as far as divs. You have to manually edit the function any time you want to add a div. The questioner may have accepted your answer which is fine, but since he had not elaborated about this needs at the point I answered the question, I think my answer was equally valid.

Comment: I just assumed that if he is using functions, he want in a future to call them more than once, but since he copy-pasted code, it is not safe to make this assumption, so you are probably right